# Setting up a custom Pre-processor in IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I am looking at developing a pre-processor and wanted to know how to configure IIS to pass the requesting page to it before it is returned. For example, the user would navigate to a page with a ".app" extension and IIS would send the file to a console program I wrote to be interpreted, before sending the page back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into developing a custom [`HttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I did but am unsure how to actually read the contents of the file. I overloaded ProcessRequest and it passes the HttpContext over, but do not know how to do the actual read.

Comment: @EricHarms - Then I would suggest asking a much more specific question about your specific issues.